# Blackberry 10 Cascades: How do i load data into a textbox?

Tags: database, sqlite, blackberry-10

I'm working on an application which requires to load data from a database into a text-box/label while clicking a button. How do i do it ?? can anybody provide me a sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting a value in a text box or label is as simple as setting the appropriate property in each. For a [Label](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__label.html?f=label) or a [TextField](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__textfield.html?f=textf) is the text property.

To get information from a data base start by [searching the documentation for SQL](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/search/?search=sql&searchaction=Search).

However the most straight forward way, depending on your actual problem, may be to use the [SqlDataAccess](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__data__sqldataaccess.html) class to feed a DataModel and a ListView.

Comment: i dont want to retrieve data into a list view. I only want to retrieve it into a textbox or a label. Please provide sample code where there is a textbox and data is retirieved into it when a button is clicked. Please ........ !!

Comment: What you are asking for is a non-trivial amount of code, much of it depending on the specifics of your problem.